# Can a date be converted to day-of-week month dd within xsl?

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I am using an xsl stylesheet to extract and display selected data from an xml file on a website.

One of the data elements is a date in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.  I would like to display it as, for example, Wed. May 10. Is this possible?

My overall project is to take an xml file, extract 3 data elements and put them out in a sorted order with the date display modified. I have a `js` for this conversion, but without the sorting. It seemed that xsl was the answer to the sorting question but now I don't know how to (or if I can) 'intercept' the date and apply a js conversion to it and put it out in the statement: `xsl:value-of select="StartTime/Date"`

Comment: Have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16488149/2115381.

Comment: Are you planning to run XSLT in a browser? If so, you're probably stuck with XSLT 1.0, which has much less date-conversion capability than 2.0.

Comment: Saxon-CE gives you the ability to use XSLT 2.0 in the browser, which immediately makes available all the date-and-time capabilities of XSLT 2.0, including format-date().

Answer (score 4):

XSLT is quite capable of basic arithmetic, and the day of the week can be derived using [Zeller's formula](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence).

You would need to call the template from your own code using

```
<xsl:call-template name="date-format">
  <xsl:with-param name="yyyy-mm-dd" select="StartTime/Date"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

This stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="date-format">
        <xsl:with-param name="yyyy-mm-dd" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="date-format">
    <xsl:param name="yyyy-mm-dd"/>

    <xsl:variable name="yyyy" select="substring-before($yyyy-mm-dd, '-')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mm-dd" select="substring-after($yyyy-mm-dd, '-')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mm" select="substring-before($mm-dd, '-')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dd" select="substring-after($mm-dd, '-')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Y">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$mm &lt; 3"><xsl:value-of select="$yyyy - 1"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$yyyy + 0"/></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$Y mod 100"/>
    <xsl:variable name="c" select="floor($Y div 100)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="$dd+0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$mm &lt; 3"><xsl:value-of select="$mm + 12"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$mm + 0"/></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="w" select="($d + floor(($m + 1) * 2.6) + $y + floor($y div 4) + floor($c div 4) - $c * 2 - 1) mod 7"/>

    <xsl:variable name="www">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$w = 0">Sun</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$w = 1">Mon</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$w = 2">Tue</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$w = 3">Wed</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$w = 4">Thu</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$w = 5">Fri</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$w = 6">Sat</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="mmm">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$mm =  1">Jan</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm =  2">Feb</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm =  3">Mar</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm =  4">Apr</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm =  5">May</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm =  6">Jun</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm =  7">Jul</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm =  8">Aug</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm =  9">Sep</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm = 10">Oct</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm = 11">Nov</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$mm = 12">Dec</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($www, '. ', $mmm, ' ', $d)"/>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to this XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <date>2013-01-01</date>
  <date>2013-05-24</date>
  <date>2013-12-25</date>
  <date>1957-07-13</date>
  <date>1776-07-04</date>
</document>
```

produces this output, as required

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
   <date>Tue. Jan 1</date>
   <date>Fri. May 24</date>
   <date>Wed. Dec 25</date>
   <date>Sat. Jul 13</date>
   <date>Thu. Jul 4</date>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

As LarsH mentioned, this is much easier in XSLT 2.0. Here's another 1.0 option if you don't have any dates earlier than 1901-01-07.

**XML Input** (Thanks Borodin!)

```
<document>
    <date>2013-01-01</date>
    <date>2013-05-24</date>
    <date>2013-12-25</date>
    <date>1957-07-13</date>
    <date>1901-01-07</date>
</document>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="date">
        <xsl:variable name="weekday" select="((xs:date(.) - xs:date('1901-01-06')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')) mod 7"/>
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(.,6,2)"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="getWeekday">
                <xsl:with-param name="weekday" select="$weekday"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="getMonth">
                <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,9,2)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getWeekday">
        <xsl:param name="weekday"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$weekday=1">Mon. </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$weekday=2">Tue. </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$weekday=3">Wed. </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$weekday=4">Thu. </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$weekday=5">Fri. </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$weekday=6">Sat. </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$weekday=7">Sun. </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getMonth">
        <xsl:param name="month"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month='01'">Jan </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='02'">Feb </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='03'">Mar </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='04'">Apr </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='05'">May </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='06'">Jun </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='07'">Jul </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='08'">Aug </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='09'">Sep </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='10'">Oct </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='11'">Nov </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month='12'">Dec </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<document>
   <date>Tue. Jan 01</date>
   <date>Fri. May 24</date>
   <date>Wed. Dec 25</date>
   <date>Sat. Jul 13</date>
   <date>Mon. Jan 07</date>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks Lars Michael and Daniel.  Lots to look at,  lots to learn. I should be able to work things out with this help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ddwrt:FormatDate()

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@EventDate), 1033, 3)" />
```

The result will look like this:

```
Thursday, May 8, 2014
```

[More Info On ddwrt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505323.aspx#officesharepointddwrt_formatdate)

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT. There is no `ddwrt` in XSLT (and no `FormatDate()` in XSLT 1.0).